# `ImportError: no module named numpy` inside an IPython2 notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm running Anaconda on Windows 7 (I've only installed it today, and have just begun learning, so please bear with me). I'm trying to run a command on IPython Notebook that involves Numpy, but for the life of me, it keeps telling me that there is `no module named numpy`.

[image: Here's a photo of the problem]

I've already done `pip install numpy` and Anaconda tells me: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in <insert folder name here>`

so I'm not really sure where the problem is coming from. :((

I've already downloaded the .zip file for numpy, but I'm not sure how it helps.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of IPython installed on your machine? Are you sure that you're launching the one inside your Anaconda directory?

Comment: I open the Anaconda Prompt and input "ipython notebook" to arrive at the IPython Notebook.

Comment: IPython is a substitute for the normal Python prompt. You should launch it directly rather than from inside another Python shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the notebook with an Anaconda environment, try looking at the output of:

`jupyter kernelspec list`

which outputs the kernel information:

`python2 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python2 
python3 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3`

If the path points to the Jupyter/iPython kernel for the user you might need to change it to use it within the the Anaconda environment. It needs to point to the conda env you are using, and look something like `C:\Anaconda3\envs\Env_Name\share\jupyter\kernels\python3`.

So, to remove the Jupyter kernelspec, just use:

`jupyter kernelspec remove python3`

or `jupyter kernelspec remove python2` if you're using python 2

Now, the output of `jupyter kernelspec list` should point to the correct kernel.

See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/397 for more information about this.

Comment: shouldn't he try to change the kernel from the list or install numpy for the other python , ( i. e better than removing the kernelspec )